# Why does ffmpeg output frames starting with 0001 instead of 0000?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to extract frames from a video. It all works well but something seems strange: The numbering of the output always starts with 0001 instead of 0000. Below a minimum working example, the output from the console and a picture of the generated frames. I'm using windows shell on Win10.

```
ffmpeg -i P1390752.MP4 -vframes 4 frame%%04d.png
```

Console output:

```
C:\Users\xxxx>ffmpeg -i P1390752.MP4 -vframes 4 frame%04d.png
ffmpeg version git-2020-01-15-0dc0837 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20200111
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.103 / 58. 65.103
  libavformat    58. 35.102 / 58. 35.102
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 71.100 /  7. 71.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002341f489e40] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 3600
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000002341f489e40] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 3600.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'P1390752.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2020-01-29T13:35:55.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:08.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 27084 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 26830 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 180k tbn, 100 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-29T13:35:55.000000Z
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-29T13:35:55.000000Z
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> png (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'frame%04d.png':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.102
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: png, rgb24, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-01-29T13:35:55.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc58.65.103 png
frame=    4 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.08 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0922x
video:5622kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

What I tried so far:
1) I restricted the output to 4 frames because otherwise it would take ages. But the problem remains the same when I remove the number of frames and extract the whole video. The problem persists when using a starting point with -ss and a duration.
2) When I use jpg as output I get some warnings about depreceated pixel format, but the numbering issue remains.

I can not get rid of the first two warnings concerning the keyframe, maybe this is related?

Answer (score 8):

That just happens to be the default starting index for frame sequence output. You can override it by adding `-start_number 0`.